# Where and how to celebrate Lantern Festival (last day of Chinese New Year) in Vancouver, B.C. area?

Tags: local-customs, event-based-effects, events, vancouver, festivals

Where and how to celebrate the Lantern Festival (last day of Chinese New Year) in Vancouver, B.C. area? [The Lantern Festival](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lantern_Festival), according to Wikipedia, is:

> a Chinese festival celebrated on the **fifteenth day** of the first month
>   in the lunisolar Chinese calendar. It marks the **final day** of the
>   traditional **Chinese New Year celebrations**, and usually falls on some
>   day in February or March in the Gregorian calendar. As early as the
>   Western Han Dynasty (206 BC-AD 25), it had become a festival with
>   great significance. During the Lantern Festival, children go out at
>   night to temples carrying **paper lanterns** and **solve riddles** on the
>   lanterns.

Because Vancouver has such a robust Chinese cultural presence in the city, I was wondering where the best places to celebrate the Lantern Festival is? Or what is the best way to celebrate it in Vancouver?

I did some research and came across this [Lantern in the Gardens](https://www.universe.com/events/lanterns-in-the-garden-2017-tickets-59G6CR) event in Chinatown, but I was wonder if there **are other events happening and if this is worth attending?** *(I only ask because I went to Chinatown on Chinese New Year's Eve -- and there was literally nothing going on. I had to keep checking to make sure that it was Chinese New Year Eve that night because I was so certain I got the date wrong... but I wasn't. It was all silent).*

Comment: @pnuts, haha... yeah.... I know. But I'm a foreigner here -- just living in Vancouver for a month. So "live" is all relative. I'm more of "tourist" for a month!!! :p   But even if I was long-term temporarily living there, can one not travel downtown and tour their own city? People forsake what is around them! Am I right? Or am I right? :)

Answer (score 1):

While Vancouver is [home to hundreds of thousands of Chinese residents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_Canadians_in_Greater_Vancouver#Demographics), it doesn't seem to have the Lantern Festival tradition yet, at least not on a massive scale. Google fails to turn up anything useful and searching [Flickr](https://www.flickr.com/search/?sort=date-taken-desc&text=Lantern%20Festival%20%20vancouver&advanced=1) for "lantern festival Vancouver" also fails to return any results for China-oriented events.

If you are interested in *lantern festivals* in general, rather than *lantern festivals during the Chinese New Year*, the biggest event is probably the [Annual Winter Solstice Lantern Festival](http://www.secretlantern.org/festival/), which is held on December 21st each year. Judging by the [photos from previous years](https://www.google.cz/search?biw=1856&bih=1014&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=Annual%20Winter%20Solstice%20Lantern%20Festival%20vancouver), the event is pretty big and has several lantern-lighting locations across the city:

[image]

I presume that's the reason why Chinatown wasn't particularly active: all the lantern enthusiasts celebrate on a different date.